# Convert XML file to an array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, dom

I try to convert XML file to an array in PHP. However, when reading the first array, it is not in form of key and value array.

Is there any way to convert the first data in form of Key and Value? Thanks in advance.

> readXML.php

```
function convertXMLFileToArray()
{
    $xml_file = 'customers.xml';
    $array_name = 'customer';
    //Check whether the file exist
    if(file_exists($xml_file)){
        //Read the data from xml file
        $dt = simplexml_load_file($xml_file,null,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $json = json_encode($dt);
        $outer_array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
        //Remove outer array
        $array = $outer_array[$array_name];

    }
    else{
        $array = null;
    }
    var_dump($array);
    return $array;
}
```

## Case1

> customers.xml

```
<customers>
   <customer>
        <cid>1</cid>
        <name>Adam</name>
        <age>20</age>
   </customer>
</customers>
```

#### Output

```
array(3) { ["cid"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(4) "Adam" ["age"]=> string(2) "20"}
```

## Case2

> customers.xml

```
<customers>
   <customer>
        <cid>1</cid>
        <name>Adam</name>
        <age>20</age>
   </customer>
   <customer>
        <cid>2</cid>
        <name>David</name>
        <age>23</age>
   </customer>
</customers>
```

#### Output

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(3) { ["cid"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(4) "Adam" 
["age"]=> string(2) "20" } 
[1]=> array(3) { ["cid"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(4) "David" 
["age"]=> string(2) "23" } 
}
```

Comment: what format you actually want? do `print_r()` instead of "var_dump()` and check the format

Comment: @prakashtank I want the first case should be like this ------
array(1){ 
[0]=>{ ["cid"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(4) "Adam" ["age"]=> string(2) "20"}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option (using `simplexml_load_string` instead of file):

```
function getCustomersFromXml($xml, $key = 'customer')
{
    $data = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $out = [];
    foreach ($data->$key as $item) {
        $out[] = (array) $item;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

So you load the XML data, loop the `customers` object and push each `customer` object cast as an array into your output.

https://eval.in/990764